# Connecting Django to PostgreSQL database (GeoDjango)

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I am having issues connecting to my Postgresql database with my Django website. My database is set up at Port 5434 as there is already an existing database in the default 5432 port.

This is the error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\anouphong\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\anouphong\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 127, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 505, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 223, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 270, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 246, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 211, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 199, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Anouphong\.virtualenvs\project_homecook-l563S6IX\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

This is my settings.py file in django

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5434',
    }
}
```

Hi, I figured it out. Really stupid mistake. I add two of the Database= {} configuration twice, once at the top of the file and once i the bottom and for got to delete it lol.

Comment: Try connecting directly via psycopg2 using your database settings: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect It is weird, though, that django is trying to connect on 5432. Do you have multiple databases with the same `DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS` (i.e. 'default')?

Answer (score -1):

This issue is generated for lack of permission.You should give the permission in **pg_hba** file.

- Log into your db user and then play the command `psql`. The sequensial coammnd is given bellow.

  - `sudo su - postgres`
  - `psql`
  - `show hba_file;`
  - In my case the output is `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf`. Rember this location
  - `\q`
  - `ctrl + d # for loging out from postgres user`
  - `sudo vim /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf #you can use your prefer text editor`
  - You need to change the file as shown bellow. Just change all method to **trust**.

[image: See the picture to identify where to change]

Comment: That is the nuclear option: "When trust authentication is specified, PostgreSQL assumes that anyone who can connect to the server is authorized to access the database with whatever database user name they specify (even superuser names)." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html

Comment: ha ha @CoffeeBasedLifeform This setup is for development not for production. If you want to run this setup in production it is caused a security issue. For production, only the IP or the host needs to add to this list. For development it's okay.

Comment: It's just unnecessary (and breeds bad habits). They are connecting locally via IP4 and the default auth method iirc is password authentication `md5`. They have the password and should be able to connect just fine. If they can't connect because their settings specify the wrong password, then setting everything to `trust` is bypassing the issue without fixing it.